# Why does intellicode '... is not null' when it is cleary null?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Edit:

Thanks to canton7 I will be looking into [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) as this is the C# 8 feature which is shown here.

Edit2:

TL;DR: The message "'_products' is not null here." is **purely** based on the **definition** of the variable *_products*. If it's defined as a nullable-reference-type it sais "maybe be null here" if it's defined as NON-nullable-reference-type(=normal, basic def without the '?') it will say, what is shown on the picture below. Both cases are only hints/warnings and won't change the compiled code.

##### Original Question:

Calling method:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() //ignore the Polymorphism
{
    _products = await ProdService.GetProductListAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("_products: " + _products + " | is null?: " + (_products == null));
//output: <<_products:   is null? True>>
}
```

Image:

[image]

Called method:

```
public async Task<List<Product>> GetProductListAsync()
{
    return null;
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: IntelliSense (not "intellicode") always uses _static declarations_ (such as return-types) instead of tracing code over call-site boundaries), and your `GetProductListAsync` returns `Task<List<Product>>`, **not** `Task<List<Product>>?>`, that's why it thinks it's never-null.

Comment: @somedotnetguy You have the C# 8 feature "Nullable Reference Types" enabled, [see this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and [this MSDN blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/). This adds a whole layer of static analysis to tell you when a reference type might be null, and warn you if you try and dereference something which might be null. You can disable this by setting `<Nullable>false</Nullable>` in your .csproj.

Comment: ... That should be `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>`, but I'm past the 5-minute comment-editing window

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the C# 8 feature "Nullable Reference Types" (NRTs) enabled. This adds a layer of static analysis, which tells you when a reference type might be null, and warns you if you dereference something which might be null. See [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and [this MSDN blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/).

You can disable NRTs by setting `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` in your .csproj.

The signature `Task<List<Product>> GetProductListAsync()` promises that this method will return a non-null `Task`, containing a non-null `List` of non-null `Products`.

Any code which calls this method only sees the signature. The compiler trusts that you wrote the signature correctly. Since the signature says that this method does not return null, this means that `_products` is shown as "not null".

(Think about what would happen if this method was defined in a different DLL. The compiler doesn't have the source code available to go analysing it. This sort of whole-program type inference is also very costly and fragile: it's much better to have interfaces explicitly stated by the programmer, rather than inferred.)

However, you have broken this promise in the implementation of the method, where you do return null. **This** is where the compiler moans at you. The CS8603 in your final screenshot shows the compiler complaining because the method signature promises that you won't return null, and yet you have `return null`.

If the method really can return null, then its signature should be:

```
Task<List<Product>?> GetProductListAsync()
```

This will make the warning on the `return null` go away, and `_products` will be shown as "maybe null".

Comment: Alright thanks. So can I assume then, that basically with C# 8+ enabled it is then considered best practice to return 'myobject?' whereever some method returns a reference type but is not guaranteed that it is non-null (in other words maybe null) ?! and accordingly return 'myobject' (w/o ?) if I guarantee an instance is returned ?! Thanks!

Comment: @somedotnetguy First make the decision on whether you want to use NRTs. They bring a lot of benefits, but there's a bit of learning to do. If you do enable them, then `Foo?` means a `Foo` which may or may not be null, and `Foo` means one which will not be null. This applies to local variables, method parameters, return types, fields, properties, etc, etc. It's worth starting with the docs and learning NRTs from the ground up.

Comment: one may now wonder, why this is then not strictly enforced (once enabled), so Foo would not allowed to be null (run time error), but I assume this is for backwards compatibility, so that old code doesn't break immediately?

Comment: @somedotnetguy Yes, introducing this sort of static analysis after decades of "any reference type can be null" is inherently risky. The design philosophy of NRTs is that 1) They only ever provide information; they won't break your code, and 2) They have no impact on the generated code: enabling NRTs will never change what the compiler generates. You can always promote these specific warnings to errors using `TreatWarningsAsErrors`, manually setting CS8603 etc to Error severity in your .editorconfig. It also means they can add new static analysis capabilities without it being a breaking change